# How to Filter calls in NOKIA N73

Tags: java, c++, symbian, nokia, n73

I am am new to mobile app development. But i would like to know if this is possible to intercept incoming calls on my N73 using code like Java or C++?

My second question is if this is possible then can we prevent the phone from ringing with a specified phone number from a black listed contact???

I've seen a lot of apps doing this task but i am interested in knowing if this is feasible & how this is accomplished.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can use `CTelephony` from `etel3rdparty`. Use `NotifyChange()` to subscribe to `EVoiceLineStatusChange` events. On an `EStatusRinging` event you can call `GetCallInfo()` to retrieve the remote party information, including phone number, and then decide whether to reject the call or let it keep ringing.

As far as I know, the `CTelephony` API does not have a direct method of rejecting a call but you can achieve almost the same with `AnswerIncomingCall()` followed by `HangUp()`. Your executable will need the `NetworkServices` capability.

A more hackish way to reject the call could be to use `RWsSession` to simulate pressing the red key (end key): call `SimulateRawEvent()` to send `TRawEvent::EKeyDown` and `EKeyUp` events on `EStdKeyNo`, with some delay between the events. In this case your executable will also need the `SwEvent` capability.

Comment: thx for the clear & concise answer laalto ;) but is this possible with Java also?

Comment: As far as I know, no, but since I wasn't sure, I did not include that in my answer.

Comment: OK thx between where can i find the 'etel3rdparty' dll? I cannot find it!

Comment: It comes with the SDK. Include `etel3rdparty.h` (under epoc32/include), link against `etel3rdparty.lib` (under target-specific directory such as epoc32/release/winscw/udeb or epoc32/release/armv5/lib). Never mind the location, the toolchain will pick the right version for the target you are building for.

Comment: I can confirm that JavaME doesn't have a standard telephony API. Symbian OS C++ is the way to go here.

Comment: There's a big difference between rejecting a call and answering it then hanging up.  In the first case the caller doesn't get diverted to voice mail and in the second case they do.  Depends what you want!